# Trouble installing bropages on OSX

Tags: ruby, rubygems, osx-mavericks

When I try to install bropages on Mavericks, I get:

```
$ gem install bropages
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing bropages:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    No such file or directory @ dir_chdir - /Users/christian/.gem/gems/unf_ext-0.0.6/ext/unf_ext

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/christian/.gem/gems/unf_ext-0.0.6 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/christian/.gem/extensions/x86_64-darwin-13/2.2.0- static/unf_ext-0.0.6/gem_make.out
```

And then:

```
$ cat /Users/christian/.gem/extensions/x86_64-darwin-13/2.2.0-static/unf_ext-0.0.6/gem_make.out
No such file or directory @ dir_chdir - /Users/christian/.gem/gems/unf_ext-0.0.6/ext/unf_ext
```

I'm using ruby 2.2.1 and gem 2.4.5, both managed with rbenv. Any idea what could cause this?

Comment: Got some more information? Pretty sure rubygems stores the backtrace somewhere.

Comment: I have added some additional infos.. does that help?

Comment: Sorry I just realized that it does not help, as it's the same error message..

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried it with `sudo`, I am running into the same issues as you, but my errors mentioned permissions, so I am going to go with sudo.  It is strange, as I had it installed once before, and now it no longer seems to be there.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you've installed the Xcode Command Line Tools, which brings with it a bunch of utilities, including what you need to build a gem module.

```
xcode-select --install
```

After you've installed the package, give the install another go.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using a `.gemrc` in your home directory, where you specify the `gemhome`. Instead of using a `~` for your home directory you should enter the complete path. In your example it should look as follow:

```
$ cat ~/.gemrc
gemhome: /Users/christian/.gem/
```

There must be some inconsistency between the ruby/gem tools. If you use a `~` in `.gemrc`, a subdirectory called `/current/working/directory/~/.gem` is created, while the extensions are put into your homes `/home/user/.gem/` directory.